# IndexError: list out of range in python

Tags: python, loops, arraylist

Every time I run my code, I get this error and honestly, I do not know why. My program import a text file which contains some data, that I want to evaluate with my program.

My program import the data from the text file, into a two-dimensional list. I want to search for special keywords in the list. This is my code for the searching.

```
data: list[list[str]] = [line.split() for line in fh]
        rangeOne = len(data) - 1
        for i in range(rangeOne):
            rangeTwo = len(data[i]) - 1
            if rangeTwo == -1:
                rangeTwo = 0
            for v in range(rangeTwo):
                if data[i][v] == "Kompletter":
```

Changing the `v` to 0 or other variations, seemed to not have any influence. I still get this error. I inserted a `print()` function before the `if` query, and the second `for-loop` ran 4 times before I got the error.

Some of the list-items are empty and looks like this `[[]]` in the console. I think this could cause the problem.
`data = {line.split() for line in fh}`
So I tried to create a dict, but then I can't split the line.
I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: *"Some of the list-items are empty and looks like this [[]]"* Can you show an example of the list?

Comment: @nokla here is an example of the list `[['Fahrzeugverlauf'], ['Kompletter', 'Verlauf'], [] ]`. I use the code in my question, in other parts of my code with other keywords and there it work without an error. When I change the keyword from `"Kompletter"` to for example `"Steuergerät"`, it works. But this is not, what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code like this:

```py
def check(data: list[list[str]]):
    for row in data:
        for word in row:
            if word == "Kompletter":
                return True  # found your word
    return False  # didn't find your word

data: list[list[str]] = [line.split() for line in fh]
res = check(data)
```

You can then do your work base on the `res`.

Comment: Thank you :). I wrote my code in the beginning not like how you would suggest it, because I also want to save only some of the `list` items in a variable. But I guess, I have to change my code like yours and add some other variables .